# R shiny error: Can't access reactive value outside of reactive consumer inside the shinyServer function

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Apologies if this question has indeed ben answered already - I couldn't find anything relevant enough.

I'm trying to host an `InteractiveComplexHeatmap` on a `shiny` app, and add the option to subset the heatmap based on cutoff values.

In the code example below the call to the `makeInteractiveComplexHeatmap` is generated inside an `observeEvent` in the `shinyServer` `function` and I set the cutoff parameters as `renderUI` called in the `shinyServer` `function`:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(InteractiveComplexHeatmap))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ComplexHeatmap))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))


server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  set.seed(1)
  mat <- matrix(rnorm(10000,0,1),nrow = 1000, ncol = 10,dimnames = list(paste0("gene",1:1000),paste0("pair",1:10)))
  
  output$negative.cutoff <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("negative.cutoff","Set negative cutoff",min=min(mat),max=0,value=0)
  })
  
  output$positive.cutoff <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("positive.cutoff","Set positive cutoff",min=0,max=max(mat),value=0)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$negative.cutoff, input$positive.cutoff,{
    hm <- mat
    if(!is.null(input$negative.cutoff)){
      idx <- which(apply(hm,1,function(x) all(x <= input$negative.cutoff)))
      if(length(idx) > 0) hm <- hm[-idx,]
    }
    if(!is.null(input$positive.cutoff)){
      idx <- which(apply(hm,1,function(x) all(x >= input$positive.cutoff)))
      if(length(idx) > 0) hm <- hm[-idx,]
    }
    if(!is.null(hm)) {
      hm <- Heatmap(hm,show_row_names=F)
      hm <- draw(hm)
      makeInteractiveComplexHeatmap(input, output, session, hm, "heatmap")
    } else {
      output$heatmap = renderPlot({
        grid.newpage()
        grid.text("Filtering removed all rows")
      })
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Paralog pair KO Effects Explorer",windowTitle="Paralog pair KO Effects Explorer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML(".multicol {-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */column-count: 3;}")),
        tags$style(type="text/css", "#loadmessage {position: fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;width: 100%;padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 100%;color: #000000;background-color: #CCFF66;z-index: 105;}"),
        tags$style(type="text/css",".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }")),
      conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",tags$div("In Progress...",id="loadmessage")),
      uiOutput("negative.cutoff"),
      uiOutput("positive.cutoff")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      InteractiveComplexHeatmapOutput(heatmap_id="heatmap",title1="heatmap",title3="cell info",
                                      width1=800,height1=800,width3=400,height3=300,
                                      action="click",response="click",output_ui_float=F)
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7716
Warning: Error in $: Can't access reactive value 'negative.cutoff' outside of reactive consumer.
ℹ Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?
  58: <Anonymous>
  57: signalCondition
  56: signal_abort
  55: rlang::abort
  54: $.reactivevalues
  49: server [#14]
   3: runApp
   2: print.shiny.appobj
   1: <Anonymous>
Error in input$negative.cutoff : 
  Can't access reactive value 'negative.cutoff' outside of reactive consumer.
ℹ Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# code before is all good
  observeEvent(
    c(input$negative.cutoff, input$positive.cutoff),
    handlerExpr = {
# code after is all green
```

It's always a good habit to not omit argument names. [This style guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/syntax.html#argument-names) may be of help for you :)